# Need to append zero before value using VB, Windows application using visual studio 2019

Tags: vb.net

In iteration i need to append zero before the Iterator. If the iterator value is less than 10 need to "00", if it is greater than or equal to 10 then need to add "0". I tried few possibilities  but the value of "J" is not updated with Zeros. Please help how to proceed.

If i added this expression in watch and check the value it is showing "000", but Variable J is not updating with the value for further validations.

```
*******

Dim int_DoubleZero As Integer = "00"
Dim int_SingleZero As Integer = "0"
Dim J As Integer

xl_LastUsed_Row = xlSH.UsedRange.Rows.Count
xl_LastUsed_Column = xlSH.UsedRange.Columns.Coun

For J = 0 To xl_LastUsed_Column
    If J < 10 Then
       J = CStr(int_DoubleZero) + Cstr(J)
    ElseIf J = 10 And J < 100 Then
        Format(J, "00")
       J = CStr(int_SingleZero) + Cstr(J)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Leading zeroes will be removed from an integer. You're concatenating a String & then that gets cast back into an integer when assigned to `J`.

Comment: @ItsPete How to retain added zeros or how to add zeros for integer?

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeroes. Leading zeroes is only a meaningful concept when you have a `String` containing digit characters. If you have a number that you want to pad to three characters with zeroes then just use proper VB.NET code, i.e. `myString = myNumnber.ToString("000")`. That will create a three-digit `String` with as many leading zeroes as are required.

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating a String & then that gets cast back into an integer when assigned to `J`. This strips out the leading zeroes that were in the string. You'll want a String variable to retain the new values.

```
Dim int_DoubleZero As Integer = "00"
Dim int_SingleZero As Integer = "0"
Dim J As Integer
Dim k as String

xl_LastUsed_Row = xlSH.UsedRange.Rows.Count
xl_LastUsed_Column = xlSH.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For J = 0 To xl_LastUsed_Column
    If J < 10 Then
       k = CStr(int_DoubleZero) + Cstr(J)
    ElseIf J = 10 And J < 100 Then
       k = CStr(int_SingleZero) + Cstr(J)
    End If
Next
```

Manipulating a loop iterator is typically bad practice as it could cause unexpected issues. `J` will also end up as the last iteration of your loop.

Comment: No need to for any `If` statement. Just call `J.ToString("000")`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s presumed you are using `Numeric` data as `String` as otherwise doesn’t make sense have a number 001 as it’s 1 or 0001.5 as it’s 1.5. So, for a String representation of your numbers you can use:

```
.Padleft(length, Char)
```

Example:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 111
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString.PadLeft(3, CChar("0")))
Next

' here are also decimals inside 
Console.WriteLine(CStr(1.25.ToString("N2")).PadLeft(6, CChar("0")))
```

Or you can use a direct format String as follows:

```
'for Integers
.ToString("000")

For i As Integer = 0 To 111
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("000"))
Next

'for Decimals 
.ToString("000.00")

For i As Integer = 0 To 111
    Console.WriteLine((i + (0.7)).ToString("000.00"))
Next
```